# iOS backboardd crash while pressing Home button on my App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, sigabrt

I'm using XCode 4.6.2 and am building for target 5.0 and above. My iPhone App is crashing in various screens when Home button is pressed. The crash log indicates 'backboardd' has crashed . In fact I don't see any log related to my APP. I can only reproduce this issue on device, and never on simulator. I commented out all the code in applicationDidEnterBackground() delegate, but the crash is still reproducible. Here's a snippet of the crash log. Any suggestions on what can be the reason for backboardd crash or any pointers - where else can I look ?

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  11

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32c2529e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a8ca97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32b7d2fa -[__NSSetM addObject:] + 582
3   backboardd                      0x000ee49e 0xd8000 + 91294
4   backboardd                      0x000ee7a8 0xd8000 + 92072
5   backboardd                      0x000eeb1e 0xd8000 + 92958
6   backboardd                      0x000ed7cc 0xd8000 + 88012
7   backboardd                      0x000efdc6 0xd8000 + 97734
8   backboardd                      0x000f05a4 0xd8000 + 99748
9   backboardd                      0x000f6e3e 0xd8000 + 126526
10  backboardd                      0x000f6d2e 0xd8000 + 126254
```

Thanks !

Comment: just clean the simulated/derived data/project and make sure all the framework associated with it are connected in it.

Comment: @iphonemaclover - Cleaning the build doesn't help. And can you please elaborate "all the framework associated with it are connected in it" ? Thanks !

Comment: add break points in different places and then try to point out where it exactly crashes...also make a break point in applicationDidEnterBackground! and then press home button if the break point reached there then you can get more exact point where it crashing

Comment: applicationDidEnterBackground exits normally, i verified it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem. It was my obfuscation tool which was causing all DB names to be corrupted. Just a newer version of the tool fixed the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had spy ware on my IPhone.. That is the reason for my crash . Look under data usage the spy ware is identified under cover up names . Mine was listed under Addh..

Answer (score -2):

change in the info.plist file

```
Application does not run in background : NO
```

Let me know it's work or not?